# Weather observation station 20 Hackerrank

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, window-functions

```
WITH s AS (SELECT lat_n, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY lat_n) r
FROM station)
SELECT lat_n
FROM s
WHERE r = count(*)/2
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help?

I am trying to find the median of the latitudes, so for that I am trying to find the middle elements.

Comment: Last time I looked hackerrank's mysql version was too old to support CTEs and window functions. Please check version.

Answer (score 0):

A small correction is necessary in your use of aggregate function near the end of your code: Try this:

```
WITH s AS (SELECT lat_n, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY lat_n) r FROM station) SELECT lat_n FROM s WHERE r = (SELECT count(*)/2 FROM station);
```